# Laravel. How to order by one field but first get items with specific value of another field?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I got a database with entries. Each entry have start date and state fields. What I want to do is order entries by start date (done that) but first display ones that have state of 0 then the others (also ordered by start date) i'm also paginating data. Now order by date and pagination is pretty easy to do, but got no idea how to do that other thing.

Comment: `orderBy("start_date", "desc")->orderBy("state","asc")` or the other way around?

Comment: could you explain more, like what exactly you have problem with?

Comment: @apokryfos Problem is that state can be 1,2,3,4 and I only care about 0 or not 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following build shows `state=0` first, then ordered by date descending. You can call either `->get()` or `->paginate()`.

```
$builder = Model::where('something', '>', 'value')
    ->orderByRaw("IF(`state` = 0, 1, 0)  DESC")
    ->orderBy('date', 'DESC');

return $builder->paginate(15);
```

To order first ones by `date ASC` and the other ones by `date DESC`:

```
$builder = Model::where('something', '>', 'value')
    ->orderByRaw("IF(`state` = 0, 1, 0)  DESC")
    ->orderByRaw("IF(`state` = 0, date, 1)  ASC")
    ->orderByRaw("IF(`state` = 0, 1, date)  DESC");
```

I just split ordering into 3 different conditions.

Comment: thanks ! but is it possible to order them different way ? What I mean by that is order ones with state of 0 desc and other asc while still applying your rule (0 first)

Comment: if `0` can change, you can replace it with placeholder and pass values to `orderByRaw` as a second argument.